# Use the wordpress premium theme but not looks like demo theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I use this theme , when I install this theme not looks like the demo, I refer the documentation and uploaded the .dat and .xml file for dummy data.

https://themeforest.net/item/pixiebolt-esports-gaming-theme-for-clans-organizations/19336338

Answer (score 0):

After installing and activating your theme you need to look for import data function in wordpress left side panel after clicking on import in that function then it will start copying the dumpy content of the website from the developer server to your site.

Comment: yes @Dnyanesh I already do this, but in my when uploading the dummy data my page getting nothing to action for that. I use these theme docs..https://documentation.pixiesquad.com/pixiebolt-esports-gaming-theme-for-clans-organizations/streams-general-settings

Comment: might file while downloading may be corrupted, so redownload the file and have an attempt at it.